# cannot run the ios simulator or the storyboard

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have the latest Xcode(which is 12) and Xamarin ios(which is 14) but i'm having trouble running the program. the problem is not my code because i created another project which was new and i couldn't run that one either. i tried on mac too and got the same error. here is the error and i would really appreciate it if someone helped me, i have been searching for answer for days.

**ERROR:**
system.aggregateexception: one or more errors occurred. ---> system.aggregateexception: one or more errors occurred. ---> monotouch.design.client.invalidsessionexception: error in the application. at monotouch.design.client.serverprocessconnection.sendrequest(commandrequest req, boolean throwifnotrunning) at monotouch.design.client.serverprocessconnection.sendrequest[tresponse](commandrequest req, boolean throwifnotrunning) at monotouch.design.client.serverprocessconnection.createsession() at monotouch.design.client.serverprocessconnection.b__28_0() at system.threading.tasks.task`1.innerinvoke() at system.threading.tasks.task.execute() --- end of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at microsoft.visualstudio.telemetry.windowserrorreporting.watsonreport.getclrwatsonexceptioninfo(exception exceptionobject) --- end of inner exception stack trace --- at system.threading.tasks.task.throwifexceptional(boolean includetaskcanceledexceptions) at system.threading.tasks.task`1.getresultcore(boolean waitcompletionnotification) at system.threading.tasks.task`1.get_result() at monotouch.design.client.iphonedesignersession.<>c__displayclass276_1`1.b__1(task`1 t) at system.threading.tasks.continuationresulttaskfromresulttask`2.innerinvoke() at system.threading.tasks.task.execute() --- end of inner exception stack trace --- at system.threading.tasks.task.throwifexceptional(boolean includetaskcanceledexceptions) at system.threading.tasks.task.wait(int32 millisecondstimeout, cancellationtoken cancellationtoken) at system.threading.tasks.task.wait() at monotouch.design.client.iphonedesignersession.<>c__displayclass276_0`1.<ensuresession>b__0() at system.threading.tasks.task`1.innerinvoke() at system.threading.tasks.task.execute() --- end of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter.throwfornonsuccess(task task) at system.runtime.com

Comment: Could your running simlulator in the XCode directly? like this thread https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/running_your_app_in_the_simulator_or_on_a_device ,  If you cannot run it normally, this issue is related to the Xcode.

Comment: thank for your suggestion. i will try your way but i'll rather not to run it on xcode.

Comment: yes it works on xcode but its not working on either mac or windows visual studio.

Comment: I search this error and cannot found related inforatiom, it is hard to reproduce this issue, you can open an support ticket(it is not free) for this issue: https://support.serviceshub.microsoft.com/supportforbusiness/onboarding?origin=%2Fsupportforbusiness%2Fcreate%3FsapId%3D211dd84f-3474-c3c5-79bf-66db630c92a6